# Can I 'earmark' a specific instance in RDS to be my writer instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm using Aurora PostgreSQL on RDS for a database cluster with one writer and one reader instance.

I have large analytical queries running on the reader every few minutes only and the writer has > 500 writes per minute.

I've tested my service both with `db.t4g.medium` and `db.t4g.large` instances.

- When using `db.t4g.medium`, my writer goes into the burst mode and uses it's credit balance gradually, my reader never does and builds it up to the maximum in less time than the write uses it up.
- When using `db.t4g.large`, both writer and reader are doing fine.

I'm wondering if I could somehow use one of two strategies to manage this more cost effectively:

- Trigger a failover each time one of the instance has more than 2x the CPU credit balance of the other.
- Set up unbalanced instances one `db.t4g.medium` and the other one `db.t4g.large` and trigger a failover if the smaller instance ever ends up being the writer for an extended period.

Comment: How much is your time worth? Will you recover the cost of implementing this solution in a reasonable timeframe?

Comment: How well can your application deal with the dropped connections when you do a failover? Is it worth interrupting in-flight transactions?

Comment: @kdgregory it's designed to be tolerant of interrupted connections that's not an issue at all.

Regarding time, spending a day automating this would be cheaper than 12 months of running the more expensive instances.

Comment: Well, if I were to do this, I'd probably set an alarm on the instances' `CPUCreditBalance` metric, and use that to trigger a Lambda when the credit balance goes to 0. That Lambda would then decide whether the cluster met your criteria and trigger the failover.